# Multithreading and shell operations causing unexpected results

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I expect this script test.rb:

```
t1 = Thread.new{1000.times {puts `echo 1`}}
t2 = Thread.new{1000.times {puts `echo 2`}}
t3 = Thread.new{1000.times {puts `echo 3`}}

t1.join
t2.join
t3.join
```

to print 1000 of `1`, 1000 of `2`, and 1000 of `3` (without any specific order).

But I get results like this:

```
root@1b3f36672857:/# ruby test.rb | sort | uniq -c
    999 1
   1000 2
   1001 3
root@1b3f36672857:/# ruby test.rb | sort | uniq -c
   1002 1
   1000 2
    997 3
```

I use `ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-linux]`.

Do you know what the problem is, and whether there is any solution for this issue?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. I get `1000 1\n1000 2\n1000 3`.

Comment: Hmm.. tested it on 3 different machines. It seems, that it happens much more often when run inside docker container, but still, I am able to reproduce this on host.

Comment: It looks like it is much easier to reproduce, when there are more threads and more digits. With 6 threads it gives me bad results even on host almost every run.

Comment: I think I was able to reproduce it on my machine by increasing the number of iterations: `100000 1, 99994 2, 100003 3`. Not sure where the issue lays though.

When I tried removing the `echo` (just doing `puts "1"`) and set the number of iterations even higher, I could still see differences in the numbers: `1000002 1, 1000000 2, 999998 3`.

Whatever messes up the counts seems to increase in likelihood with larger iteration numbers and decrease in likelihood with faster iterations.

Comment: It seems like a race condition that can happen when multiple threads try to write to `STDOUT` simultaneously. I think the following questions discuss some similar situations and hopefully one of the solutions can help you: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750903/ruby-multithreading-questions), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044299/whats-the-easiest-way-to-print-output-from-parallel-operations-in-ruby-without)

Comment: @Pending Well, problem in my project is more complex. It was simplified for asking question. My original problem isn't related with output printing, but with git operations (using git gem). In the result, it  happens that sometimes two different threads have to do some operations on different git repositories, like this:
1) `git --git-dir=/repos/firstRepo/.git --work-tree=/repos/firstRepo add -- firstFile`
2) `git --git-dir=/repos/secondRepo/.git --work-tree=/repos/secondRepo add -- secondFile`

Comment: @Pending In my code, there are not public variables that could be overriten by another thread or anything like this. But sometimes, these 2 operations result with broken repositories (fatal errors, missing blobs, etc), sometimes result looks like the command that was really executed looked like this:

`git --git-dir=/repos/secondRepo/.git --work-tree=/repos/firstRepo add -- firstFile`